# How to annotate an annotation with another annotation in java?

Tags: java, validation

I want to create a custom annotation and annotate it with another annotation like below:

```
@Documented
@Target({ElementType.PARAMETER, ElementType.FIELD})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
//@Size(min = min, max = max, message = defaultMessage) //neither this works
//@Min(6) //nor this works
public @interface PasswordString {
    String message() default defaultMessage;

    Class<?>[] groups() default {};

    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};

    class PasswordStringAnnotationConfig {
        public static final int min = 6;
        public static final int max = 100;
        public static final String defaultMessage = "Password must be between " + min + " and " + max + "characters";
    }
}
```

I know I can simply create a class that implement `ConstraintValidator` but I wonder if I can achieve this easier functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

adding this annotation

```
@Constraint(validatedBy = {})
```

solved the problem.

Although this annotation is present in the declaration of `Min` and of `Size` annotations, but I don't know why it was not applied on the custom annotation automatically and needed to be defined explicitly.